# How does the parameter 'dim' in torch.unique() work?

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to extract the unique values in each row of a matrix and returning them into the same matrix (with repeated values set to say, 0) For example, I would like to transform

```
torch.Tensor(([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4],
              [1, 6, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4]])
```

to

```
torch.Tensor(([1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 6, 3, 5, 0, 0, 4]])
```

or

```
torch.Tensor(([1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 6, 3, 5, 4, 0, 0]])
```

I.e. the order does not matter in the rows. I have tried using `pytorch.unique()` and in the documentation it is mentioned that the dimension to take the unique values can be specified with the parameter `dim`. However, It doesn't seem to work for this case.

I've tried:

```
output= torch.unique(torch.Tensor([[4,2,52,2,2],[5,2,6,6,5]]), dim = 1)

output
```

Which gives

```
tensor([[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  4., 52.],
        [ 2.,  5.,  6.,  5.,  6.]])
```

Does anyone have a particular fix for this? If possible, I'm trying to avoid for loops.

Comment: I have the same problem, do you have a solution？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One must admit the `unique` function can sometimes be very confusing without given proper examples and explanations.

The `dim` parameter specifies which dimension on the matrix tensor you want to apply on.

For instance, in a 2D matrix, `dim=0` will let operation perform vertically where `dim=1` means horizontally.

Example, let's consider a 4x4 matrix with `dim=1`. As you can see from my code below, the `unique` operation is applied row by row.

You notice the double occurrence of the number `11` in the first and last row. Numpy and Torch does this to preserve the shape of the final matrix.

However, if you do not specify any dimension, torch will automatically flatten your matrix and then apply `unique` to it and you will get a 1D array that contains unique data.

```
import torch

m = torch.Tensor([
    [11, 11, 12,11], 
    [13, 11, 12,11], 
    [16, 11, 12, 11],  
    [11, 11, 12, 11]
])

output, indices = torch.unique(m, sorted=True, return_inverse=True, dim=1)
print("Ori \n{}".format(m.numpy()))
print("Sorted \n{}".format(output.numpy()))
print("Indices \n{}".format(indices.numpy()))

# without specifying dimension
output, indices = torch.unique(m, sorted=True, return_inverse=True)
print("Sorted (no dim) \n{}".format(output.numpy()))
```

---

**Result (dim=1)**

```
Ori
[[11. 11. 12. 11.]
 [13. 11. 12. 11.]
 [16. 11. 12. 11.]
 [11. 11. 12. 11.]]
Sorted
[[11. 11. 12.]
 [11. 13. 12.]
 [11. 16. 12.]
 [11. 11. 12.]]
Indices
[1 0 2 0]
```

**Result (no dimension)**

```
Sorted (no dim)
[11. 12. 13. 16.]
```

Comment: Could you explain how `return_counts=True` works with `dim` set? I don't get it from the official docs.

Comment: If you look again at your example, you will notice that what is returned is a tensor of unique columns (dim=1) and the duplicate values have no relation to the maintenance of any shape. For dim=0 the returned tensor would contain unique rows.

Answer (score 6):

I was confused when using [torch.unique](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.unique) the first time. After doing some experiments I have finally figured out how the `dim` argument works.
Docs of [torch.unique](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.unique) says that:

> counts (Tensor): (optional) if return_counts is True, there will be an additional returned tensor (same shape as output or output.size(dim), if dim was specified) representing the number of occurrences for each unique value **or tensor**.

For example, if your input tensor is a 3D tensor of size `n x m x k` and `dim=2`, `unique` will work separately on `k` matrices of size `n x m`. In other words, it will treat all dimensions other than the dim `2` as a single tensor.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer and the accepted answer is wrong.