# How can I zero out duplicate values in each row of a PyTorch tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torch

I would like to write a function that achieves the behavior described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54262689/how-does-the-parameter-dim-in-torch-unique-work).

That is, I want to zero out duplicate values in each row of a matrix in PyTorch. For example, given a matrix

```py
torch.Tensor(([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4],
              [1, 6, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4]])
```

I would like to get

```py
torch.Tensor(([1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 6, 3, 5, 0, 0, 4]])
```

or

```py
torch.Tensor(([1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 6, 3, 5, 4, 0, 0]])
```

According to the linked question, `torch.unique()` alone is not sufficient. I want to know how to implement this function without a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x = torch.tensor([
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4],
    [1, 6, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4]
], dtype=torch.long)

# sorting the rows so that duplicate values appear together
# e.g., first row: [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
y, indices = x.sort(dim=-1)

# subtracting, so duplicate values will become 0
# e.g., first row: [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0]
y[:, 1:] *= ((y[:, 1:] - y[:, :-1]) !=0).long()

# retrieving the original indices of elements
indices = indices.sort(dim=-1)[1]

# re-organizing the rows following original order
# e.g., first row: [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0]
result = torch.gather(y, 1, indices)

print(result) # => output
```

**Output**

```
tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 6, 3, 5, 0, 0, 4]])
```

Comment: @MustafaAydın added.

Comment: I think you could use the `tensor.diff()` method to handle the subtraction portion

Comment: It's a pity that such a non-intuitive construct is needed, simply to check for and handle duplicates per row...